# How can I pass a list of parameters to Jenkins from a file

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I need to pass a list of parameters to Jenkins from a file written in this way

```
param1=test1
param2=test2
paramBool=true
....
```

How can I pass these parameters?
I have to use the parameters in a Jenkins pipeline

Answer (score 1):

I mentioned before [a dynamic declarative pipeline parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72528814/6309).

You might combine it with:

- either [`readFile`](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#readfile-read-file-from-workspace)
- or [`load`](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-cps/#load-evaluate-a-groovy-source-file-into-the-pipeline-script), which can evaluate a Groovy source file into the Pipeline script, and [modify `params`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64120833/6309).

Comment: But I would pass the file with the parameters uploading it using the Jenkins interface (parameter file)

Comment: @pakolela "pass the file with the parameters", as in "pass the file location/full path, or pass the file content?

Comment: I don't have the file in the workspace so: file content

Comment: @pakolela OK, the [groovy script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64120833/6309) can use that file content, once split into lines, then key-value, and modify `params`.